# Animate pygame sprite in elliptical path

Tags: python, animation, pygame

This is pygame 1.9 on python 2.6..

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IydcA.png) of what is currently being drawn in my "game" to give some context. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Z6qPdzLH) is the code.

It's supposed to be the moon orbiting around the earth (I'm not trying to make a real simulation or anything, I'm just using the setting to play around and learn pygame). It's 2 circles, and the moons elliptical orbit around the earth. My end game is to have the moon follow it's orbit around the earth, but I want to later use keyboard controls to adjust the shape of the moons orbit.

I really just need help with figuring out how to make the moon follow the path, I could probably figure the rest out.

Answer (score 5):

Well here is how you generate points along an ellipse:

```
for degree in range(360):
    x = cos(degree * 2 * pi / 360) * radius * xToYratio
    y = sin(degree * 2 * pi / 360) * radius
```

`(x,y)` will follow an ellipse centered at `(0,0)`, with the y radius being `radius` and the x radius being `xToYratio`. In your case, you probably want `degree` to be related to time passing somehow.

EDIT: you can also do this:

```
for degree in range(360):
    x = cos(degree * 2 * pi / 360) * xRadius
    y = sin(degree * 2 * pi / 360) * yRadius
```

where `xRadius` is half of your rect's width, and `yRadius` is half of your rects height. Visualize it intuitively - you have a circle, and you're stretching it out (i.e. scaling it, i.e. multiplying it) so that it's as big as the rect horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I think is generally what I need to do, but part of my problem is I'm not sure how to find the radius of the ellipse since i define the ellipse by using the Rect class (see my code).

Comment: It would perhaps be convenient not to work in degrees... If you have many sprites and you call an update function on them all once per tick, degrees make for a very messy integration. If anyone wants I will post a version that works this way once I code it.

Comment: What's the difference between degrees and something else?